# app engine: communicate with Java app behind firewall

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to have a Java-Application that is behind a firewall (maybe even connected over a 3G modem) and I have a google app-engine application.

How can the gae app push data to the clients?

I found some ways that look promising, but I'm not sure what will really work.

- Sockets will not work, because I cannot connect through the firewall/3G barrier
- the [channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/) only works with JS clients
- [XMPP](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/) looks very promising - the client would report it's presence and the server could push chat-messages to the client and also the client could reply that way.

  But what about user-accounts? i.e. could I use a single XMPP-account for all users (and let the client send a unique ID to identify the user) - or is a unique XMPP account for every device (which runs the java-aplication behind the firewall) required?

are there any other options or are there some XMPP gotcha's you know about?